# Different docks on different workspaces, or configure awn to behave differently on different workspaces

Tags: workspaces, dock, awn

I would like to have different settings for the dock behavior for different workspaces, or more likely i would like the dock that i use now , awn (Avant window navigator) to show up in just 3 of the four workspaces i have.

So the question is : can i run different instances of awn one on each workspace

or can i run it just on one work space and maybe use something else like cario for the next workspace.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

you can edit a script that change your AWN's gconfs, for example change your dock behavior from "intellihide/panel-mode" to "autohide" so you no longer see it..
then you can add it to your dock as a "simple launcher" entry..

[this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7361685/etc/awn-panel-behavior-switch.sh)
is a script i've done to move my wingpanel and my dock to the left, resizing them to 20px and forcing them to auto hide.. it works like a switch so re-launching it makes everything back to normal..

hope it helps..

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.